# Python How to sort list in a list

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list within a list. This is what I have. I would like to sort the inner namelist based on alphabetical order. Have tried using loops but to no avail. The smaller 'lists' inside happens to be strings so I can't sort() them as list. Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'

```
Names = [
    [['John'] ['Andrea', 'Regina', 'Candice'], ['Charlotte', 'Melanie'], 
    ['Claudia', 'Lace', 'Karen'] ['Ronald', 'Freddy'], 
    ['James', 'Luke', 'Ben', 'Nick']]
]
```

I would like it to be sorted into:

```
[
    [['John'] ['Andrea', 'Candice', 'Regina'], ['Charlotte', 'Melanie'], 
    ['Claudia', 'Karen', 'Lace'] ['Freddy', 'Ronald'], 
    ['Ben', 'James', 'Luke', 'Nick']]
]
```

Thank you. 
Edit: Sorry i made a mistake in the previous codes. Ive since edited it.

Comment: Loop over the outer list, and call sort on the inner lists.

Comment: @Estelle  show us what have you tried so far, ?

Comment: [Change `Names` to `names`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 4):

```
Names = [sorted(sublist) for sublist in Names]
```

This is a list comprehension that takes each sublist of `Names`, sorts it, and then builds a new list out of those sorted lists.  It then makes `Names` that list

Comment: sorry, i've copied the wrong code. the inner list happens to be strings so i can't sort them.

Comment: @EstelleMontgomery strings can be sorted.  Have you tried the line above?

Answer (score 2):

The built - in list method: `sort()` works in-place on sub lists if you iterate over them:

```
Names = [['John', 'Andrea', 'Regina', 'Candice', 'Charlotte', 'Melanie'], ['Claudia', 'Lace', 'Karen', 'Ronald', 'Freddy'], ['James', 'Luke', 'Ben', 'Nick']

for sublist in Names:
    sublist.sort()
```